# C function to remove vowels in a string not working?

Tags: c, string, pointers

Here is my function to remove the vowels in a string;

```
char *removeVowels(char *inString) {

    int count = 0; //to count the non vowel characters

    for (int i = 0; inString[i]; i++)
        if (inString[i] != 'a' || inString[i] != 'e' || inString[i] != 'u' || inString[i] != 'o' || inString[i] != 'i')
            inString[count++] = inString[i]; //if character is not a vowel placed at count++  

    inString[count] = '\0';

    return inString;
}
```

The problem is that it is returning the original string inputted. Any ideas?

Comment: You need &&'s, not ||'s in your if line. Every character will match your current condition.

Comment: What terminates the loop? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @natersoz it'll terminate when seeing the null termination character

Comment: @natersoz: the center statement in the `for` loop, the end test clause, takes care of that. It's equivalent to `while(inString[i])` (and `i++` would be somewhere inside the loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a confusion between the `||` and `&&` operators. You want to test that the character is different from `'a'` **AND** different from `'e'` etc.

Here is a modified version:

```
char *removeVowels(char *inString) {
    int count = 0; // index for preserved characters

    for (int i = 0; inString[i]; i++) {
        if (inString[i] != 'a' && inString[i] != 'e' && inString[i] != 'i'
        &&  inString[i] != 'o' && inString[i] != 'u') {
            inString[count++] = inString[i]; // copy the non-vowel character
        }
    }
    inString[count] = '\0';  // set the null terminator.

    return inString;
}
```

Note however that uppercase vowels are not removed by this function, and whether `y` should be considered a vowel remains to be decided.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in another comment, you need to use && instead of || to make sure that the character does not match any vowels.  It might be easier to create a new string and add non-vowels to that string as you go.  Something like:

```
char *removeVowels(char *inString, int size){
    char newString[size];
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(inString[i] != 'a' && inString[i] != 'e' && inString[i] != 'i' && inString[i] != 'o' && inString[i] != 'u'){
            newString[count] = inString[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    newString[count] = '\0';

    return newString;
}
```